# how to zoom out of embedded website - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I have embedded a website onto my website but the problem is that it is too zoomed in. I have to scroll right and left every other second. I can make the size of it bigger but that way I wouldn't have enough space for other things on the web page.

How would I zoom out of this website to fit perfectly??

view the pic and the code below

HTML:

```
<iframe id="czar" src="https://www.smc3.com/czarlite.htm"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
#czar {
    width: 825px;
    height: 70vh;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[Embedded Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LiIL.png)

Comment: You can try the [zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) property

Comment: Would it be possible to put your code into a runnable snippet that the community could test?

Comment: unfortunately there is some confidential stuff on the website, so I wont be able to share the code for the whole website.